# Does Espresso UI test framework supports Webviews?

Tags: android-espresso

From searches I did in web, I came across few people's views that Espresso UI Test framework does not support WebViews? Is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Espresso supports WebViews and I have added one sample example below
http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/2016/02/testing-web-views-using-espresso-web.html